# Postgres Debezium does not publish the previous state of a record

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I successfully installed `Postgres Debezium CDC`. Now, I'm able to catch all changes happening to the database. But the problem is "before" field always stays empty. So, if I insert a record `(id = 1, name = Bill)` I then get from Kafka this data:

```
'payload': {'before': None, 'after': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bill'}, ...
```

But if I update the record like so:

```
UPDATE mytable set name = 'Bob' WHERE id = 1
```

I get this from Kafka:

```
'payload': {'before': None, 'after': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}, ...
```

This is how I configured my connector:

```sh
curl -X POST  localhost:8083/connectors/ \
  -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \
'{
    "name": "test-connector",
    "config": {
         "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
         "tasks.max": "1",
         "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
         "database.hostname": "postgres",
         "database.port": "5432",
         "database.user": "postgres",
         "database.password": "postgres",
         "database.dbname" : "test",
         "database.server.name": "postgres",
         "database.whitelist": "public.mytable",
         "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
         "database.history.kafka.topic": "public.topic"
    }
}'
```

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you get messages from Kafka?

Comment: @Iskuskov Alexander. I tried consumers in two languages - PHP and Python. They both get messages from Kafka and print their body and in both cases I see that `before` property is None (in Python) or null (in PHP).

Comment: Did you consume from the earliest offset? Are you sure that message `'payload': {'before': None, 'after': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}` is about update event and not about the insert event that you read again? Please show more data in messages

Comment: @Iskuskov Alexander. I'm consuming from the start. In PHP for example, I do it like so `$topic->consumeStart(0, RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_BEGINNING);`. And I'm totally sure, that the message with `name: Bob` is an update event, because it pops up, when I manually execute `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Beside, `id` field is serial, so it's impossible to have two records with `id = 1`

Comment: Hm. I noticed this in connector logs: `REPLICA IDENTITY for 'registry.schema_version' is 'DEFAULT'; UPDATE and DELETE events will contain previous values only for PK columns`. It seems like this is the whole problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try to execute this command: `ALTER TABLE public.mytable REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;`

Comment: @Iskuskov Alexander. Yeah, it works!

Comment: It's great! I've moved my comments to the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`before` is an optional field that if present contains the state of the row before the event occurred. Whether or not this field is available is highly dependent on the `REPLICA IDENTITY` setting for each table.

[`REPLICA IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-REPLICA-IDENTITY) is a PostgreSQL specific table-level setting which determines the amount of information that is available to logical decoding in case of `UPDATE` and `DELETE` events.

To show the previous values of all the table’s columns, please set the `REPLICA IDENTITY` level to `FULL`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.mytable REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;
```

See more details in the [Debezium docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#events).